# warning php_network_getaddress

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So here is my code:

```
class database{
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db_name){
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db_name,$username,$password);
    }
}

try{
    $db = new database('localhot','root','','first_database');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

This works when connecting. But when there is an error, like when localhost is misspelled I get two error messages, such like:
[image]
I really don't understand why this is happening? My previous connection with mysqli_connect worked perfectly. Trying to get a handle on OO n PDO.

Any advice? Thank-you.

note: in simplest possible terms please :)

Comment: please attach image in question.

Comment: What you see is NOT an error. It is a warning. You do not error handling at all, otherwise you could react on the error. For example by throwing an exception which can get caught in the calling scope where you implemented your try catch construct.

Comment: AFAIK The PDO constructor shouldn't even throw a warning, but should indeed throw an exception. What is line 5? It looks like your database is what spitting out the warning and not the pdo constructor. Is this really your code?

Comment: nvm I just reread your warning message..

Comment: I'm getting the impression from responses that PDO isn't the way to go? Or I'm doing it spectacularly wrong.

Comment: How is your php ini on mysql section? Your code does not throw warning in my environment. Maybe the cause is the way how to it try to connect to mysql.

Answer (score -1):

you should use (PDOException)

```
try{
    $db = new database('localhost','root','','first_database');
 }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) is the provided link for the PDOException class.

Answer (score -2):

PHP Errors and Warnings are not catchable in a try catch block.  Only Exceptions that are explicitly thrown in code are.

If you want to trap errors and warnings generated by PHP you will have to register an error handler using [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)